# Autocomplete Textview not filtering the items

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have DialogFragment. There are 2 scenarios.

1. When I click on the button, this dialog gets opened. When I start typing, it filters the contents. After saving the entered data, dialog gets closed.
2. (Issue observed in this scenario) Now If I open the dialog again, it doesn't filter while typing. Why this is happening. It filters in the first scenario. Then why it's not filtering in the second scenario. Is anyone facing a similar issue..Can anyone help me to find a solution for this problem.

Please find the filtering code

```
Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return filter;
    }

        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            public String convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
                String str = ((ItemDto)(resultValue)).name; 
                return str;
            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                if(constraint != null) {
                    mSuggestions.clear();
                    for (ItemDto item : mItemsAll) {
                        try {
                            if(item.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())){
                                mSuggestions.add(item);
                            }
                        } catch (Exception ex){}
                    }
                    FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                    filterResults.values = mSuggestions;
                    filterResults.count = mSuggestions.size();
                    return filterResults;
                } else {
                    return new FilterResults();
                }
            }
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                ArrayList<ItemDto> filteredList = (ArrayList<ItemDto>) results.values;
                if(results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    clear();
                    for (Itemdto c : filteredList) {
                        add(c);
                    }
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: you wont get any help unless you show some code..

Comment: post code then only someone can help you.

Comment: have you think we are here to doing your home work ?